# Trying to resolve ambiguity concerning SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_* flags

Tags: c++, c, winapi, https, winhttp

I'm using [WinHttp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WinHttpQueryOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384103(v=vs.85).aspx) API in particular to ensure that my connection employs strong https encryption. For that I'm doing the following:

```
DWORD dwHttpSecurityFlags = 0;
DWORD dwcbSzSec = sizeof(dwHttpSecurityFlags);
if(WinHttpQueryOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwHttpSecurityFlags, &dwcbSzSec))
{
    //Check security -- for connection to employ 128-bit encryption
    if((dwHttpSecurityFlags & SECURITY_FLAG_SECURE) &&
    (dwHttpSecurityFlags & (SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_WEAK | 
        SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_MEDIUM | 
        SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG)) == SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG)
    {
        //Passed security check
    }
    else
    {
        //Security check failed
    }
}
else
{
    //API Failed
}
```

But I'm not very clear how [SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_* flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx#WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS) are used -- as bitwise flags, or as one-only values?

If I look in a header file, they are defined as such:

```
#define SECURITY_FLAG_SECURE                    0x00000001 // can query only
#define SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_WEAK             0x10000000
#define SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_MEDIUM           0x40000000
#define SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG           0x20000000
```

which hints at bitwise use, but it doesn't make sense for a connection to use both 40-bit and 128-bit strong encryption.

Can someone clarify this? Is my code above correct?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to check? I don't understand your condition code.

Comment: @torvin: `Check security -- for connection to employ 128-bit encryption`

Answer (score 1):

As clearly stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is a bitwise flag field:

> WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS
>
> Sets or retrieves an unsigned long integer value that contains the security flags for a handle. It can be **a combination** of these values.

If you need to check for 128-bit encryption specifically, then this is the right code:

```
if (dwHttpSecurityFlags & SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG) {
   // Passed security check
}
```

as `SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG` means 128-bit encryption:

> SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG
>
> Uses strong (128-bit) encryption. This is only returned in a call to WinHttpQueryOption.

**EDIT:**

The documentation is not 100% clear which flag is going to be set in which situation. After looking at [the source code of Wine](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/9d3fda008f07d9651df2c0894403b46d59e46845/dlls/wininet/netconnection.c#L582) it becomes clear that `SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_*` flags are mutually exclusive. But other flags, like `SECURITY_FLAG_SECURE` could be set together with one of the `SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_*` (which is exactly what documentation is saying).

Comment: What would it "clearly" mean if both `SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_WEAK` and `SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG` flags are set then?

Comment: They won't be set both, but `SECURITY_FLAG_STRENGTH_STRONG` could easily be combined with other flags. So you should not be guessing which flags could be combined and just use the code provided above. It will work in any case.

Comment: Do you have any references to that? If what you said is true, this contradicts the definition of the `bitwise flag field`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field and that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: What exactly do you find contradicting the bit field definition?

Comment: Not in a bit field definition, [your explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751415/trying-to-resolve-ambiguity-concerning-security-flag-strength-flags/32753122?noredirect=1#comment53382397_32753122) is contradictory: `"They won't be set both"`

Comment: OK, finally I understood what is bothering you. I'll update my answer

Comment: OK. Appreciate the Wine link.